# What should a Hindu son do after the death of his father?

Tags: temple, death, prayer, funeral

I am the youngest son of 3 brothers and my father passed away yesterday.  I went to the temple yesterday to seek the help of a pandit for funeral and cremation, when at the temple he mentioned that I should not enter the actual temple until my father has been cremated (actually I'm not sure if I should wait till the actual ashes are disbursed, or just wait till after the cremation).  Why is it that I cannot enter the temple?

Am I allowed to pray at home?  What should I be doing in these days other than planning the funeral/cremation, and notifying close family and friends of my father?

What should I be doing and what should I not be doing at this time?

Comment: Sorry to hear about it. You should not be praying till your father's funeral is completed. There are restrictions on worshiping god for 10/11 days. Suthak is followed according to your community traditions(It varies in different castes). You may learn more from a pundit.

Comment: You should not visit temple or do puja at home till all post death ceremonies your community are over.  Cremation, asthi-visarjan, various day shraddhas etc. If you edit the question to add name of your community, if there are users here from your community, they will be able to help you. https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/rituals-to-be-performed-after-cremation-till-the-13th-day-after-death  This link gives example from one tradition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly you had to do mukhagni (fire the body at cremation place) on third day you had to go to cremation place and put the ashes in Lota(Vessel) then you had to go Haridwar and deposit ashes of your father in Ganga River.On 13th day you had to organize a Function (Mrityu Bhoj) or Death feast  in which you and your family had to serve food to the persons come in Mrityu bhoj (In some areas there is tradition of Brahmana Bhoj ) All the food your guests will eat some portion of the food and Good wishes will be given to your father in the trip of heaven .You can't do prayers till the 12 or 13 days after the death because in these 13 days you had to do all the responsibility of a son. It is believed that Aatma or soul of a person live in his home till the 13th day of his death with his all relative. If you went to temple then the Soul will also go with you and that will make the temple Impure because this soul hasn't got his place in Heaven or hell. Also it is believed if you do any prayer than it will not with purity because you have done cremation of your relative and cremation  place is taken a place where ghost are said to be live so it is a Impure place so you can't do prayer till 13th day in your home or temple because the badness or impurities of cremation place is with you till the 13th day. After 13 days you can do any prayer at any place like home or temple. In Hinduism we are not allowed to Make  the festival's on large scale if there is a death in home for 1st year. You can't celebrate festival on large scale but you can celebrate the festival on small scale. Like in Holy you can celebrate this but within a limit you can go out color your relatives but in a limit.You can Celebrate with your relative or close ones. you can go to your relatives home or homes of people close to your family. You shouldn't celebrate with all person for eg. Neibours ,friends , colleagues you should celebrate with few one only relatives and person close to you .You had to celebrate first festival with  your whole Family You had to Celebrate festival with your whole family for eg. If a person has three son and two daughters after his death the whole family of his three sons had to celebrate the festival at the home of their father or where their father was living and for daughters they can come alone or they can come with husband to their Father's home to celebrate the festival after 1st festival you can Celebrate other separately or if you want to do it jointly you can do it .

Comment: @Yash Welcome to Hinduism.SE! You should cite sources, preferably Hindu scripture, in your answers. Please take a look at [Guidelines for new users for answering questions](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/125/2995) and other [FAQs](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).