# Death Time for Grandmother

Tags: atma, death, time, superstitions, customs

My Grandmother(Father's mother) aged 88 has passed away on Thursday 22/03/2018 inbetween 3PM to 3:15PM due to natural death inside the hall of the house. Strange thing is that she said at 3:10PM saying that she is goint to die, die.
She didnt have any health issues majorly and she was happily living. Questions are:

1. Is her death time good or bad?
2. Few people said it is bad time and we need to close the house for a period of 9 months. Is this true?
3. Since she passed away in the hall, can we close the hall alone or should we close the entire house?
4. What will happen if we dont close the house for 9 months?
5. Will closing the house for 9 months get rid of the bad things that might happen?
6. What is the logic behind the death and closing the house?

Pls explain.

Comment: Your grandmother died. There is nothing you can do about it. Move on!

Comment: There are no good and bad times for death.  Death is the end of the present life and as per Sanatana Dharma the soul moves on as per its karma. Even in life there is no scientific basis for favourable or unfavourable time for actions. Lord Krishna has beautifully enunciated it in Bhagavad Gita. The body is perishable, the soul is not. And at the age of 88, it is expected that a person is near the end of his life, a few more or less years to live. The basic concept in Sanatana Dharma is if a person has completed all his duties as a human being, which your grandmother definitely has, (continued)

Comment: (continued) if a person has completed all his duties as a human being, which your grandmother definitely has, then her death cannot bring harm to any of her near and dear ones. Please do not get misled by the advice of either people of little learning or the ones with vested interest, like the pandits and others who make hay while the relatives mourn. Move on ahead. No harm will befall, whether you close the house or not.

Answer (score 1):

I won't be able to answer all the questions but let me try.

1.) The time was Amrit (which is best) but this time was overlapped with Rahu kala (which is inauspicious).

2.) I have never heard of that. What I have heard is that you don't touch your god idols at home for 13 days or host any event for 6 months or so. (Recommendation - you and all your family members should do prayer and give it to you grand mother)

3,4,5,6) Again, never heard of it so don't know this one. May be this is regional base, that's why I might have not heard of it.

General recommendation fr this condition - You can do some puja (Shraddha Ritual) for your grand mother. Do lots of prayers and give it to your grand mother. Distribute food and cloths in poor, go to temple, etc. But everything should be for your grand mother, so she can rest in peace.

Comment: Don't believe in everything that everybody says. Hinduism is not a religion of blind faith. There is always a logic behind everything.

Comment: You may do purification ritual for your home. sorry - forgot to add that.

Comment: You can click on [edit] and modify your answer whenever you want.

Comment: https://www.oursubhakaryam.com/mruti_death_marana_day_dosham.html.

Comment: Pls see the link i gave. in that it says to vacate house

Comment: this above link does not mention any scripture on which basis they are proclaiming this. In north india, upto my knowledge no hindu sect follows this, neither any folk/local tradition I am aware -where death itself has vaara dosha or nakshatra dosha. But one thing can be concluded from your link https://www.oursubhakaryam.com/contact_our_subhakaryam_team.html mentions that this website is by Godavari District, Andhrapradesh. So this website "may be" referring to some local customs/local text of East Godavari District.

Comment: In that case, if you do not belong to that East godavari district community, then there are thousands of sects and innumerable non-scriptural conventions there. These days unknown texts are being marketed as vastu-dosha texts. If you do belong to that district, no need to follow these conventions, this way haphazard local convetions are being marketed on internet and website as some core text of hinduism, which is false.

Comment: It is probably only a regionalism. In Kerala, e.g., it is considered sinful to eat food with *uzunn* (black gram, e.g., idli, pappad) if one is performing *bali* and has thus touched the corpse before cremation. The *pula vratam*, as it is called, is lifted after the *pathinaar adiyantharam* (performed sixteen days after the cremation) and *pula kuli* (purifiying bath).

Answer (score 0):

1) (rituals for just after death for next few days)= If you are Smarta or non-denominational or Agamic Hindu, then go for Garuda Purana based 13 day death ritual. If you are follower of pure Vedic customs, then go for 3 or 5 days Arya Samaj or Srauta rituals.

2) After 13 days your home is considered pure again.So you can perform any small scale worship . Hence, Either on 14th day Or after a few days or week or month, you may - 'get a Vedic yagna performed at home(say, Arya samaj pundit can perform it)' Or 'a satyanarayan swami puja' or 'may be both' -can be performed at home, in memory of your grandmother.

3) Perform pinddaan at Gaya at appropriate time.

Nothing else is required.

Comment: also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16955/what-should-a-hindu-son-do-after-the-death-of-his-father and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/death-in-family-does-a-marriage-need-to-be-postponed and also see https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-dos-and-donts-after-a-death-in-a-Hindu-family